# Cordova 10/11 iOS app not able to open google maps URI

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

After upgrading to cordova 11 from cordova 9, I am unable to open a google maps URI (On Button click Cordova app should open Google maps with the co-cordinates)

What worked in cordova 9:

```
var coord = lat + ',' + lon;
window.open(`comgooglemaps://${coord}?q=${coord}`, `_system`);
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme

Now, this does nothing. No errors or logs.

Working config: `Cordova 9`, `cordova-ios 5.1.1`

Current config: `Cordova 11`, `cordova-ios 6.2.0`

Comment: I suspect there might be some config settings in the `config.xml` file that I am missing

Comment: My issue was with the installed InAppBrowser plugin. I've done as they suggested: 

window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

But this no longer seems to work. As soon as I did:

window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(`comgooglemaps://${coord}?q=${coord}`, `_system`);

it started working again.

Comment: Thanks @Leo. This is the answer. Please post this and I will accept

Comment: Great to hear - happy if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was with the installed InAppBrowser plugin.

I've previously done as they suggested:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

But this no longer seems to work. As soon as I changed the code to use InAppBrowser explicitly:

```
window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(`comgooglemaps://${coord}?q=${coord}`, _system);
```

it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `geo` instead

```
 var coord = lat + ',' + lon;
 window.open('geo://'+coord, `_system`);
```

Or

```
 window.open("http://maps.apple.com/?q="+coord, '_system');
```

Comment: Does not work. Also, geo is for Android